# Microsoft Bot Framework - Development Environments

Tags: bots, botframework, azure-bot-service

I started learning Microsoft bot and coming across different environments to build and test. I am trying to understand the exact purpose of all environments.

Bots can be developed using Visual Studio using c# or Node.js in our local machine after downloading the Bot Template. Also, It can be tested in our local development machine using the Bot Emulator. I am clear till this point.

In one article, I could see that Bots can be built using https://dev.botframework.com/bots. When should we go for this environment?

Also, Bot Service can be enabled in Azure (portal.Azure.com). How it differs from the previous dev.botframework.

Can someone clarify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are developing a bot locally, the environment you described is perfect.

However, once you want to allow others to access your bot and from different channels (Facebook Messenger, Skype, etc), you will likely host it in a cloud platform, let's say, Azure. Once you do that, in order to allow the Bot Framework infrastructure to interact with your bot you will have to authenticate your bot against that infrastructure. For that to happen, you will have to register your bot in https://dev.botframework.com/bots whereyou will get your Microsoft AppId and your Microsoft AppSecret, that then you will use in your bot code (in `C#` in the `Web.config`, in `Node.js` usually in a `.env` file).

[image]

You can read more about this on the [How the Bot Framework works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/overview-how-bot-framework-works) documentation topic.

Regarding Azure Bot Service: it an integrated environment that is purpose-built for bot development, enabling you to build, connect, test, deploy, and manage intelligent bots, all from one place. You can write your bot in `C#` or `Node.js` directly in the browser using the Azure editor. Your bot is automatically deployed to Azure.

You can read more on https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/bot-service/

Comment: Hi...Thank you for the detailed explanation. If i understand correctly, i dont need to use dev.botframework.com if i completely build bots using azure bot service. i need dev.botframework only if i develop locally and try to deploy in azure and require other channels to communicate. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Yes, that's sounds accurate. Please mark the question as answered.

Comment: Sure... Thanks a lot!